# Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4.18 and 2 sites configure

Tags: apache, https, configuration

I have a new Ubuntu server, on the old server (12.something) we had api.mysite.com and portal.mysite.com running. We have since moved portal.mysite.com to the new server but now I am stuck getting the api to work.

I have the ip of api.mysite.com in my local windows 7 hosts file set to the ip of portal.mysite.com and it is my understanding that if I go to api.mysite.com(on my machine with the fudged ip in the hosts file) it will go to the new server but the header for my request will identify to apache that I want to go to api and not portal.

I am pretty sure that I am hitting portal - the config file on portal is set to redirect / to https://portal.mysite.com and that is not how I know - it is because there is a ServerAlias on portal that is portal.**prod**.mysite.com and if I go to api.mysite.com I end up at https://api.**prod**.mysite.com/

portal currently redirects to https and when I am done I want api to redirect to https as well. Portal has been running fine on the new server for a few weeks no.

What am I doing wrong? I need portal and api to run on the same server.

Thank you

API:
[image: API config]

And portal:

[image: Portal config]

Comment: Your config files would help debug the issue. Of course obscure any sensitive information.

Comment: I have access to config files.

Comment: Ok, share your config files! That way people can tell you "see, this line here is the problem".

Comment: I just added it to the question, I have no idea if I can attach a file to a question.